# What does "you can't gaffa the gaffa" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "you can't gaffa the gaffa" mean? Saw a t-shirt with such print and couldn't translate correctly

Comment: In BrE 'gaffer' is the boss. But 'gaffer' or colloquially (see Kate Bush song) 'gaffa' also refers to gaffer tape. So 'can't gaffa the gaffa' may (I repeat, may) be something to do with taping over something.

Answer (score 5):

[Gaffa](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=gaffa) is British slang for "boss".

The phrase you saw means "you can't [boss](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/boss) the boss"

Note that *boss* can be used as a noun

> Your **boss** is the person in charge of the organization or department where you work.

and a verb

> If you say that someone **boss**es you, you mean that they keep telling you what to do in a way that is irritating.

The spelling of "gaffa" derives from [gaffer](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gaffer)

> People use gaffer to refer to *the person in charge of the workers* at a place of work such as a factory.

This is an informal use of the word.

Formally a [gaffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaffer_(filmmaking)) is the senior electrician responsible for lighting in films or TV productions. The gaffer's assistant is known as the [best boy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/best-boy).

Comment: +1 My first instinct was to say that ***gaffer*** was a corruption of *governor*. But the OED, whilst recognising its substitution for *governor* gives an etymology which links it to *godfather*. - *The analogy of the continental synonyms, French compère, commère, German gevatter, would suggest that gaffer, gammer are contractions of godfather, godmother rather than of grandfather, -mother; but the change of vowel may be due to association with these words.*
 *1. A term applied originally by country people to an elderly man or one whose position entitled him to respect.*